# import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward cannot be resolved

Tags: firebase, admob

I am trying to deploy in my App the RewardedVideoAd of Admob, but when I put the import of the library I get this error:

import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward cannot be resolved

Someone knows why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It took 5 days to get it. I did receive no answer from here... but thinking in all those people that will face this problem in the future, I want to say my solution, and this is: create a complete new project from a .metada from 0, and import the new version of google play service lib (very easy to get here in stackOverflow) , import it. If you have a facebook project, remove it, and import from 0 as well. When you have finished to import all your libraries, create a new project, the yours, and copy, file per file, everything. This will work for sure.